# Counterexample for convergence of series of iterated $\ln$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, examples-counterexamples

While messing around with some convergent series for a bit, I thought of the following problem:
Let $f_n(x)$ be defined recursively by $f_0(x) = x$ and $f_n(x)= \ln(\vert f_{n-1}(x)\vert)$ and let $(a_k)$ be such that $f_n(a_k)$ is well-defined for all $k$.

> Assuming $a_k\in\mathbb{R}^+$, $\sum_{k=1}^\infty {a_k}$ converges, need
> $\sum_{k=1}^\infty {a_k f_n(a_k)}$ converge also?

After some experimentation, I found a set of counterexample for the case $n=1$, given by $a_k = \frac{1}{k\ln(k)^{1+\epsilon}}$, where $\epsilon\in\left(0,1\right)$.

However, despite quite a bit of effort, I couldn't construct any counterexamples for $n\geq 2$. I strongly suspect that a counterexample exists for each $k$, but was unable to prove this result.

Comment: If $n>1$ and $0<a_k<1$ then you are going to get complex numbers in your sum. Is that expected?

Comment: @TurlocTheRed In the version I considered, I had absolute value bars, I modified the question as to reflect that. I also mentioned that $a_n$ is chosen sufficiently small such that $f_n(x)$ is always well-defined.

Comment: As you did for $n=1$¡ taking $a_k=\frac{1}{k\log (k)\log(\log(k))\cdots \log(\log(\cdots\log(k)))^{1+\varepsilon}}$ is a counterexample for any $n$ (where the last $\log$ in the fraction is iterated $n$ times, and $\varepsilon$ is any value in $(0,1)$

Comment: @charmd It is not immediately clear to me why this series should converge... Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: You can look at the "generalized Bertrand series" in this wiki article: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test